# Magento 2.4.2 : List of core modules which can be disabled to improve performance optimization

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

What are the core magento modules which can be disabled if unused? For the **M2.4.2**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This varies based on your requirements and can't be answered in one Stack Exchange post. For example if you don't need configurable products then disable Magento_Configurable. We can't really answer that for you.

Comment: Thanks @BenCrook for the information.

Answer (score 3):

If you look for the Yireo Github page, you'll see Jisse has implemented the folllowing so that it removes those modules with a composer.json file

```
"replace": {
    "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-magento-2-module": "*",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-and-login-with-amazon-core-module": "*",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-module": "*",
    "amzn/amazon-pay-sdk-php": "*",
    "amzn/login-with-amazon-module": "*",
    "magento/module-braintree": "*",
    "magento/module-braintree-graph-ql": "*",
    "braintree/braintree_php": "*",
    "braintree/braintree": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-package": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-enterprise-package": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-chat": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-b2b": "*",
    "dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension-sms": "*",
    "klarna/m2-payments": "*",
    "klarna/module-core": "*",
    "klarna/module-kp": "*",
    "klarna/module-kp-graph-ql": "*",
    "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
    "klarna/module-onsitemessaging": "*",
    "paypal/module-braintree": "*",
    "paypal/module-braintree-core": "*",
    "paypal/module-braintree-graph-ql": "*",
    "temando/module-shipping": "*",
    "temando/module-shipping-m2": "*",
    "temando/module-shipping-remover": "*",
    "vertex/product-magento-module": "*",
    "vertex/module-tax": "*",
    "vertex/sdk": "*",
    "vertexinc/module-tax-staging": "*",
    "vertexinc/product-magento-module": "*",
    "vertexinc/product-magento-module-commerce": "*",
    "vertex/module-address-validation": "*",
    "vertex/module-tax-staging": "*",
    "yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews": "*",
    "yotpo/magento2-module-yotpo-reviews-bundle": "*"
  }"
```